# Difference between Correlation and Causality inexistent?

Tags: discussion

For many arguments here I have seen in the top comments the common killer phrase:

***Correlation does not imply causation***

However, especially because this phrase comes from people with a certain understanding of statistic, in my options this is nonsense. Especially in times of big data and highly cross-correlated the use of causality should be considered obsolete.

Modern physics does not even argument with causality anymore.
The CERN works on the statistical 6σ basis which is a confirmation of 99.9999998027%, or in other words, a false positive detection of 1 in 506 797 346 (the observed physical effect was just pure coincidence).

To demonstrate the absence of any causality let me use this example:

**Example**: Is gravity the causality of an apple following to the ground?
**Answer**: No, its just a correlation because there is no way to prove it will happen the next time again, but it is considered highly likable. How likely?

Well we were 107billion people so far since ever, lets assume everyone makes 1 observation of the effect of gravity in every second doing nothing else for his entire life (<60yrs in average). This even neglecting the fact how long humanity though "things simply fall down".

[image]

So how large is the false positive rate, meaning that we observe gravity even though it does not exist: 11.033σ

**Example**: Is fire the causality of my fingers burning on the oven?
**Answer**: No, just a high number of sigma caused by a high number of observations. Highly likable but no way to prove it was not just a coincidence.

Graphic [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPALs.png)] No sigma values on the axis obviously, medicine has other standards than physics. The y-axis is more of a fuzzy logic, possibly both values true at the same time.

Qualitative speaking at a certain point correlation becomes causality in the mind of people (Who considers the two examples as "not causality"?).
Many argue that with causality a model (of reality) is used - well a simple formula can describe the effect and the uncertainty.

[image: Causality is just a perception]

### Causality is a just a perception

Why is the word causality used if in reality it is just a very high number of correlation? Even worse when people prodly use the magic sentence above. There is no official threshold and even if? What if it is arbitrary close to it but below?

So general acceptance of causality is just an arbitrary "feeling" of the right threshold (besides physics where it seems to be 6σ.

Or the other way round: As soon there is a tiny correlation it can be considered "causality". As the threshold is arbitrary simply means correlation=causality.

Comment: You completely misunderstand what is meant by the phrase and probably haven't even read the basics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation for starters. One example of two events, which are correlated with no causal relation destroys your argument. (I.e., reading ability and physical strength are highly correlated, yet reading more won't make you strong, and going to gym regularly won't magically help you learning to read. Correlation is due to the fact that adults are better at reading and stronger than kids)

Comment: We use correlation (observation) primarily as a giant cluebat that there is probably a causal link. Causality requires you to propose a mechanism for HOW it happens. For as long as you cannot think of an explanation there is no causality no matter how well things correlate.

Comment: @sashkello "Use of correlation as scientific evidence" goes towards my direction, therefore I also don't understand the downvoting, but maybe the question is not formulated neutral. However I did my research before posting.

Comment: And you got pretty much all of it wrong.

Answer (score 8):

This question seems to boil down to definitions - you are using a different definition of "causality" to anyone else.

[Causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality) is not defined in terms of high correlation.

Umbrellas will never be considered the cause of rain no matter how high the correlation.

> The CERN works on the statistical 6σ basis which is a confirmation of 99.9999998027%, or in other words, a false positive detection of 1 in 506 797 346 (the observed physical effect was just pure coincidence).

CERN don't use this as evidence of causality, but as the likelihood that their result would have come from pure chance, had the null hypothesis been true. This is a red herring.

> Example: Is gravity the causality of an apple following to the ground?
>
> Answer: No, its just a correlation because there is no way to prove it will happen the next time again, but it is considered highly likable.

No, that is not correct.

Under the Theory of Gravity, the acceleration of the apple is causally related to the mass of the Earth.

The Theory of Gravity is informed by uncountable numbers of observations, but, like all science, could be proven wrong and relies on induction - that what happened every single time in the past will continue to happen tomorrow. If the Theory of Gravity is overthrown, our understanding of the causality of the apple falling might change. That is qualitatively different to saying "high correlation = causality".

> So how large is the false positive rate, meaning that we observe gravity even though it does not exist: 11.033σ

Ahhh... no. That's not how p-values work. You need to have an understanding of the variance in the null hypothesis. If the null hypothesis is that Newton's Laws of Motion exist, but there is no gravity, then the very first apple would not accelerate at all. As as soon as it did, there would be something to explain.

> Why is the word causality used if in reality it is just a very high number of correlation?

Because it doesn't mean that.

> There is no official threshold and even if?

There is no official threshold because it isn't on the same scale as p-values nor correlation.

Comment: `Umbrellas will never be considered the cause of rain no matter how high the correlation.`  Perfectly put.

Comment: Well the variance of could be small, it would just change the sigma value, wouldn't it? I really like the umbrella example, thank you for that. And I  also have one more question as I would really like to understand this concept. How large is the probability that umbrellas ARE the causality of rain? That's where I'm stuck with all the examples. How would you prove it without everyday logic but pure statistics? Isn't there just a threshold where u accept it even though there is like always a remaining probability?

Comment: Aside: Maybe my null hypothesis for gravity is unfair. Maybe it is that the Laws of Motion exist most of the time, but sometimes items accelerate randomly. Anyway, that is a problem I am happy to leave to Newton.

Comment: "How large is the probability that umbrellas ARE the causality of rain?" This question doesn't have an answer. You don't demonstrate causality with a calculator; you demonstrate it with an experiment. Randomly assign some days where you raise umbrellas, and some days when you don't. Do it enough times to be convinced that there is no significant difference between the two groups. Reject the hypothesis.

Comment: @stefans pearl goes over how you would prove that umbrellas don't cause rain in his book that I link in my answer.

Comment: I thought the main cause of rain was *leaving your umbrella at home*.

Answer (score 3):

You've restated [Hume's Problem of Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction) (see [also](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/#HumInd)).

Judea Pearl's [Causality](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/) covers the basics of how causality is treated in the sciences today.